# Can I make WPF ComboBox treat substring as new value?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I'm using a ComboBox defined by:

```
    <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Height="29" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="137,192,0,0" Name="componentsComboBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="224" 
              IsEditable="True"
              TextSearch.TextPath="Name">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

..to display a list of objects by their "Name" properties.  I'm observing the following behaviors:

1. Click an item in the dropdown, and componentsComboBox.SelectedValue (and .SelectedItem) correspond to the clicked item. OK!
2. Start typing the name of an item, autocomplete fills in as you type, .SelectedValue (and .SelectedItem) correspond to the autocompleted item.  GREAT!
3. Start typing the name of an item, autocomplete fills in as you type, *hit delete to truncate to only what you have actually typed*, .SelectedValue and .SelectedItem STILL correspond to the autocompleted item.  NO! BAD WPF! BAD!
4. Similar behavior to 3 if you delete characters from the end of the textbox portion

In essence, if I have a List containing two objects defined by, e.g.,

```
{ new Component() { Name = "COMPONENT1"}, 
  new Component() { Name = "COMPONENT2"} }
```

I want the values:

- COMPONENT1
- COMPONENT2

to appear in the drop-down portion, and if the user enters "COMP" I would like to recognize that they have entered a new value, but as it stands right the control makes it look like they selected COMPONENT1.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in WPF easily by setting the IsEditable and IsReadOnly properties to True & False respectively.

Ref.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable.aspx

e.g. [How can I allow users to edit text in a ComboBox in WPF?](http://learnwpf.com/post/2006/07/12/How-can-I-allow-users-to-edit-text-in-a-ComboBox-in-WPF.aspx)

```
<Window x:Class="LearnWPF.EditableComboBox.Window1" 
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
    Title="LearnWPF.EditableComboBox" Height="300" Width="300" 
    > 
  <Window.Resources> 
    <XmlDataProvider x:Key="items" XPath="//item"> 
      <x:XData> 
        <items xmlns=""> 
          <item>01</item> 
          <item>02</item> 
          <item>03</item> 
        </items> 
      </x:XData> 
    </XmlDataProvider> 
  </Window.Resources> 
    <Grid> 
      <ComboBox IsEditable="True" DataContext="{StaticResource items}" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding}"/> 
    </Grid> 
</Window>
```

Comment: This is the behavior I already have (IsEditable); it doesn't address the question of why if I type "02" in the ComboBox, and then delete the "2" from the end (leaving just "0" in the ComboBox), the ComboBox.SelectedItem, .SelectedIndex, and .SelectedValue all correspond to the value "01" whereas I would expect them to be .SelectedItem=null, .SelectedValue=null, .SelectedIndex = -1 (as they are if I type a value that is *not* a substring of one of the existing values; that's the behavior I would like to mimic for a value of "0" -- unless there is a better/supported way to differentiate).

Answer (score 0):

I experienced this behavior today and agree that on the surface, it appears to be a bug.  Digging a little deeper though reveals a bit of a gray area.

What I think is going on here is that the control is running a prefix matching algorithm every time the text box is updated, regardless of the keystrokes that cause the text box to be updated.  So when you delete the auto-completed part of the text, the prefix matching algorithm still matches an item in the control's ItemsSource; the control isn't attempting to deduce that the end-user just deleted the auto-completed portion, so the algo shouldn't run.

Re: your comment to akjoshi's response, when you delete the "2", leaving just the "0" in the combo box's text box, the prefix matching algorithm correctly matches the "01" item.

The work-around I used was to only bind to the Text property of the ComboBox and build all view model logic off of that.  SelectedItem, SelectedIndex, and SelectedValue are not bound at all.